# Sequences of numbers with colored dots above them

Tags: mathematics, pattern

[image: Question 1]
[image: Questions 2]
[image: Question 3]

How should this kind of cryptosum question be approached? Please provide step-by-step thinking for each example.

Source: Mensa IQ Check App Version 1.1.0

Comment: Also, we prefer for there to be only one question per question. Perhaps split this into multiple questions, one for each puzzle?

Comment: Is there a specific rule for how these work? You call them "cry[p]tosums", so it sounds like there's a certain set of rules you're expecting -- as-is, they seem very underspecified to me.

Comment: @Deusovi♦ Cryptosum is just a general name I found for these types of questions.

Comment: @bobble I will be aware of this for future questions.

Comment: It's fine to ask multiple if you're using them as examples of a more general type of puzzle - I edited you question assuming this was the intent.

Comment: @JasonEvans Do you know the rules for "cryptosums"? With just the images you've given, there are many possible solutions -- as a result, the only real way to solve it is to guess the particular interpretation the question writer had in mind. (As a result, many "IQ test" questions are generally not very good at testing IQ. Or anything else, for that matter.)

Comment: @Deusovi♦ I don't think there are specific rules. The goal is to solve the represented value of each colored dot to calculate the answer of the 4th column. I am just wondering how each of you would approach these type of questions.

Comment: W=White, B=Blue, E=Empty
For the left one. 
1. Divide the 2nd column by 2. W+E=16
2. Sub into 1st column. 2B+16=38
3. B=11
4. ...

This is the way I can think of.

Comment: Then there are many different ways to do it, especially if placement matters - you can assign white and blue to either "x and 2x" or "x and -x", and find a different number for each row. There would be infinitely many solutions then.

Comment: For the center one. 1. Subtract 2nd from 3rd. B-W = -3 2. Sub B=W-3 into 1st 3. 3W + W -3 =18, W= 5.25 4. ...

For the right one. 1. Divide the 1st column by 2. W+E=69 2. Sub into 2nd column. 2B+69=119 3. B=25 4. ...

Comment: @JasonEvans Judging based on your comments, I think they're just examples of [systems of linear equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) with three variables. (First: 33, Second: 28, Third: 123) I'm afraid it's a standard math problem, [which is generally considered off-topic here](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2784/71652).

Answer (score 1):

These are just simultaneous equations with 3 variables:
g=greenish blue, w=white, t=transparent
2g+w+t=38
2w+2t=32;
3w+g=41;
2t+w+g=?
Putting everything in terms of w: (82-6w)+w+(16-w) =38
Thus, w=10
Thus, g=11
Thus, t=6

You can solve others similarly.
For 2nd one more approach can be thought of:
Change from Column(2) to Column(3) = **g** changed to **w** = 2
Change from Column(3) to Column(1) = **t** changed to **w** and **g**changed to **w** = -3
Thus, **t** changed to **w** = -5
Now, Column(4) - Column(3) = **g** Changed to **t** = -(**t** Changed to **g**) = -(**t** Changed to **w** + **w** Changed to **g**) = -(-5+-2)=7
Thus, Column(4)=28

Just by observation, but first approach stands more appropriate and general.

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions - which this is, since it's a basic math problem.